# UITableView cellForRowAt if statement faulty work

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

According to the codes below, the first time I run the application.
The first 3 lines are working correctly.
But when I scroll up and down.
Some lines also change.
When I make a little more up and down
It changes to other lines

How can i solve this problem

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = KategoriEkleCell()
  var KategoriId :String = ""


    if tableView == tableView {
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! KategoriEkleCell
        cell.itemLabel.text = (AltKategoriKayit[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? [String:String])?["kategoriadi"]
        cell.itemLabel.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Light", size: 14.0)

        KategoriId = ((AltKategoriKayit[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]  as? [String:String])?["kategoriid"])!
        if (KategoriId) == (MenuKategoriKayit[indexPath.row]["kategoriid"]!) {

            cell.EkleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2
            cell.EkleButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.EkleButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 56/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            cell.EkleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 56/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.EkleButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            cell.EkleButton.clipsToBounds = true

        }else {

            cell.EkleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2
            cell.EkleButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.EkleButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 56/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            cell.EkleButton.clipsToBounds = true

        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Right employee**
[image: Right employee]

**Faulty employee. when I scroll up and down.**
[image: Faulty employee. when I scroll up and down.]

Comment: Cells are reused. Each time you set a value, you need to set it back to "origin" in other case. Like `cell.EkleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 56/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 1.0)`, which you set in one case, but don't set it to "normal" in the other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments cells are reused.

You have to ensure that any UI element is set to a defined state in `cellForRow`. I moved the duplicate lines which both are executed in the `if` and `else` branch out of the `if - else` scope for better readability.

By the way the parentheses in the if line are not needed either

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let specialRed = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 56/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! KategoriEkleCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.itemLabel.text = (AltKategoriKayit[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? [String:String])?["kategoriadi"]
    cell.itemLabel.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Light", size: 14.0)

    let KategoriId = ((AltKategoriKayit[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]  as? [String:String])?["kategoriid"])!
    cell.EkleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    cell.EkleButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.EkleButton.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.EkleButton.layer.borderColor = specialRed.cgColor

    if KategoriId == MenuKategoriKayit[indexPath.row]["kategoriid"]! {

        cell.EkleButton.backgroundColor = specialRed
        cell.EkleButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    } else {
        cell.EkleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.EkleButton.setTitleColor(specialRed, for: .normal)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Please consider that according to the naming convention variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Maybe interesting to mention that the "default" behavior could be set by overrriding `prepareForReuse()` and wouldn't be needed anymore in the `cellForRow()`